# What are the real differences between "standard" boolean logic and fuzzy logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, fuzzy-logic

Fuzzy and Boolean Logics are equally expressive and one is nothing more than syntactic sugar for the other. I'm honestly trying to get convinced otherwise.

---

**Here's my argument:**

In Boolean logic, $x \in X$ is a predicate which evaluates to one of two values, and we take one of those values to signify truth. Let us denote $V_B = \{0, 1\}$ to be the logical values of Boolean Logic.

In Fuzzy logic and non-conventional logics like Tri-State logic, $x \in X$ is a predicate which evaluates to $v$ where $v \in V$ and $V$ is the set of logical values pertaining to the logic in question.

---

Now here's what I mean when I say that Fuzzy Logic is at most as expressive as Boolean Logic:

Let $F$ parse a valid statement $s$, the answer being $v$:
$$F(s) \to v$$

Now let $B$ parse $v = k$, which is a valid statement in Boolean Logic:
$$B(v=k) \equiv B(F(s)=k)$$
$$B(v=k)\in \{0, 1\}$$

So we've changed the question:

> What is the degree of set membership of x in X?

To:

> Is **this k** the degree of set membership of x in X?

We can boil down any statement in Fuzzy Logic (or any other for that matter) to a statement in Boolean Logic.

Conclusion: Fuzzy Logic is fundamentally offering nothing more to the table than Boolean Logic already does.

Comment: Note that even basic inequalities in fuzzy logic ("The degree of set membership of $x$ in $X$ is $<{1\over 2}$") get translated to *uncountable disjunctions* on the Boolean side.

Comment: Indeed:  Fuzzy logic provides no benefits whatsoever over the unique, self-consistent, principled form of reasoning under uncertainty based on probability and Bayesian reasoning.  There are very scholarly articles demonstrating this, and to the best of my knowledge not a single elite statistics department gives courses on "fuzzy logic."  Moreover, the recent extraordinary progress in AI (e.g., machine learning and especially deep learning) is based on *probability* and ultimately Bayesian reasoning... "fuzzy logic" has contributed nothing to this advancement.

Comment: This is a strange argument. By the same reasoning, all of mathematics is offering nothing more than Boolean logic because we can reduce it to binary questions like "Is P a true statement?"

Comment: @Conifold well of course it is

Comment: In that case, fuzzy logic is in good company.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What do you mean by uncountable? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Also, how is that statement fuzzy? There's nothing inherently fuzzy about it.

Comment: How exactly can a statement like "She stands very tall."  Or "The Earth is rather large."  get boiled down to Boolean Logic?

Comment: You are missing the point of non-classical logics: classical logic is a logic of perfect information and is well-suited to pure mathematics, where we assume everything is known or at least knowable. When reasoning in situations where we have only partial information, then classical logic can be highly unnatural.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Firstly, define everything in those two statements, and the answer will come by itself

Comment: @RobArthan No, classical logic is just a mapping from statements to two truth values, non-classical logic is just a mapping from statements to whatever. That's how I see it.

Comment: Classical logic often involves formal systems where no truth values exist.

Comment: @Threnody: no, logic is about reasoning. Mathematical logic provides a mathematical model for how we reason. Classical logic is reasoning in a situation where propositions are all either true or false. In situations where we we don't have perfect information about the truth of propositions, then the nature of what you dismissively call "whatever" becomes important.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood That's new.. can you lead me to examples?

Comment: Take a look at axiomatic systems for classical logic (Hilbert calculi), or natural deduction systems, or sequent calculi.